# Making ".py" files Standalone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, cross-platform

I don't mean turning .py files into executable or anything similar to that, but a python file which can run on any machine where python is installed, without needing to install required dependencies manually.

Comment: what dependencies are you talking about?

Comment: like installing python.

Comment: @MattR Such as openCV

Comment: why not just add the dependencies in your code? `try:
    import library
except ImportError:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', 'library'])
    import library`

Comment: @MattR by doing so, can I run the same python file in different OS without need to install dependencies?

Comment: Especially with openCV, what you are aiming for is mostly impossible. Is openCV installed on the target already?

Comment: @Dschoni If it is impossible, then question ends. No openCV isn't installed on target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably want to make a package out of your python file, that installs any dependencies on the first run. This can be done using distutils or setuptools etc.

This is valid for most python packages, that can be installed via pip or easy-install or any other package manager (as conda in anaconda etc.). The problem is, that dependencies itself might not be trivial to be installed. OpenCV is a very complex framework which is not written in pure python. This is why, what you want to achieve is not possible using only one python file.

Comment: I don't want to install dependencies, I want to integrate them to the .py file so it can run cross platform without installing anything.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would like to do that. But in principle you could copy/paste all the source code of all imported modules into your main *.py file.

Comment: Is there anything better than copy pasting every library manually? that is the main question.

Comment: You are talking about openCV. This will simply not work.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the reason for it?

Comment: openCV is a quite complex library which is not written in pure python. If your target application is written in pure python, what you want could be possible but still tricky.

Comment: If it would've been an answer, I would've accepted.